# From list of str EX: dates into integers - month only

Tags: python, list, csv

Take a list of dates EX: `D = ['5/20/2016', '11/10/2016']`
into `D = [5,11]`
All I need is the months per element of dates.

I have tried replacing `/` with space, so I can move the 5 and 11 away from the other numbers. This is where I am now.

```
for i in release:

    release = [str(x.replace('/',' ')) for x in release]
```

Take `D = ['5/20/2016', '11/10/2016']`
Turn it into

```
D = [5,11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split using the slash as separator and take the first element.

```
D = ['5/20/2016', '11/10/2016'] 
release = [x.split("/")[0] for x in D]
```

`release` will be ['5','11']

And if you want the result as a list of ints:

```
release = [int(x.split("/")[0]) for x in D]
```

#### Complete answer according to the comments:

If you want to count the number of occurrences of every month and achieve a dictionary of the form

```
{'Apr': 1,
 'Aug': 1,
 'Dec': 3,
 'Feb': 1,
 'Jan': 5,
 'Jul': 1,
 'Jun': 1,
 'Mar': 1,
 'May': 1,
 'Nov': 3,
 'Oct': 3,
 'Sep': 1}
```

Then I recommend using `Counter` within the `collections`  module as in the following code:

```
from collections import Counter
releases=[1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,12]
months={1:"Jan",2:"Feb",3:"Mar",4:"Apr",5:"May",6:"Jun",
        7:"Jul",8:"Aug",9:"Sep",10:"Oct",11:"Nov",12:"Dec"}
counts = {months[month]:n for month,n in Counter(releases).items()}
```

In the example I provided a test `releases` list, as if it were the result of the previous step. Afterwards, I provided a dict mapping month numbers to strings. Despite a list with those names and indexes might work, I believe a dict is semantically better for this case because its job is to map a key:value relation.

The final line returns the result you are looking for, as dict.

Comment: How can i take this data, as its now its an int value of 1-12 per element. How can i compare lets say, if 1 appears in this list, put that specific index into a list for january?

Comment: You could always use a dictionary to convert numbers to month names or even a list or tuple. If I understand correctly.

Comment: I am taking a csv file of 679 movies, each with a release date and a number of tickets sold, its a 680 row, 6 column csv file. I need to take the release month and corellate it with tickets sold for every month. Jan = 10 tickets, Feb = 22 tickets. Like that but for 679 movies

Comment: If you have any way i could be doing this any easier please help!                 
  with open('movie.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')


    for row in readCSV:
        movie.append(row[0])
        release.append(row[1])
        distributor.append(row[2])
        genre.append(row[3])
        mpaa.append(row[4])
        tickets.append(row[5])

Comment: That is how i am reading the lines from the csv file and it creates 6 list, but from there comparing list with dates and genres and stuff is so complex.

Comment: def Dates():
    jan = []
    feb = []
    mar = []
    apr = []
    may = []
    jun = []
    jul = []
    aug = []
    sep = []
    octo = []
    nov = []
    dec = []

Comment: for i in release:
        if x in range(0,12) == release[i] in tickets:
            if x == 1:
                jan[i] = release[i]
            if x == 2:
                feb[i] = release[i]
            if x == 3:
                mar[i] = release[i]
            if x == 4:
                apr[i] = release[i]
            if x == 5:
                may[i] = release[i]

Comment: if x == 6:
                jun[i] = release[i]
            if x == 7:
                jul[i] = release[i]
            if x == 8:
                aug[i] = release[i]
            if x == 9:
                sep[i] = release[i]
            if x == 10:
                octo[i] = release[i]
            if x == 11:
                nov[i] = release[i]
            if x == 12:
                dec[i] = release[i]

Comment: I am trying this idk if my if statement is correct but nothing is stored into any of the list

Comment: You should have added all of this into your question or made a new question... I will still try to answer and edit my answer to include the details. Make sure to upvote or accept it if it helps you.